# What is the process to upgrade from Django 1.3 to 1.4 (or any other version)?

Tags: django

What is the process to upgrade from Django 1.3 to 1.4 (or any other version)?

Comment: Change it into a real question, please.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please clarify the question. StackOverflow is great to ask questions about specific issues you are having, however not so much for asking very general things. Are you having trouble installing new version? Migrating code? If code, then what specific part of code? etc. You can read more about what questions should be posted here at FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it may be difficult to upgrade the django from 1.3.1 to 1.4.1 (latest).

It is so simple for this you should have `pip` to make it easy
Take a backup copy of your resources

If you don't have `pip`

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ pip install -U django  # it will install/upgrade to latest version
```

or you need to upgrade to particular version

```
pip install --upgrade django==1.4.1
```

after the installation just confirm like this

```
$ python
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
'1.4.1'
```